# Creating a semicircle plot of angular (azimuth) data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to use MATLAB to create a figure whereby multiple data points are plotted such that their orientation (azimuth <180 degrees) is on the circumference and their width is on the radius. I have created a sketch of my intention.

Example data:

Orientation (deg)/Thickness (cm)

098/50

150/87

023/64

Is this possible in MATLAB?

[image: Sketch of intended plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`polarplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html) function in MATLAB versions starting from R2016a. For older versions you can use the [`polar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html) function, although it is very limited in terms of modifying the plot to look the way you want. Even using `polarplot`, you may find it difficult to create a plot *exactly* the way you show it above, but you can make something pretty similar:

```
% Plot data:
data = [98 50; 150 87; 23 64];
p = polarplot(data(:,1).*pi./180, data(:,2), 'kx', 'LineWidth', 2);

% Adjust axes properties:
set(gca, 'ThetaDir', 'clockwise', 'ThetaZeroLocation', 'top', 'ThetaLim', [0 180], ...
         'ThetaTick', 0:45:180, 'ThetaColor', [0 0 0], 'ThetaGrid', 'off');
set(gca, 'LineWidth', 2, 'GridAlpha', 1, 'GridColor', [1 0 0]);
set(gca, 'RLim', [0 100], 'RTick', 0:50:100, 'RAxisLocation', 0, 'RColor', [1 0 0]);

% Set axes labels:
set(get(get(gca, 'RAxis'), 'Label'), 'String', 'Thickness');
set(get(get(gca, 'ThetaAxis'), 'Label'), 'String', 'Orientation', ...
                                         'Position', [90 120 0], 'Rotation', -90);
```

And here's the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option without `polarplot`. It's a little more work, but highly adjustable:

```
% Preparations:
data = [98 50; 150 87; 23 64];
thickness = 0:50:100;
azimuth = 0:45:180;
Xax = [min(thickness) max(thickness)]; % X axis limits
Yax = [-max(thickness) max(thickness)]; % Y axis limits

% set the circle:
figure('Position',[200 200 300 400])
pos = [Yax(1) Yax(1) [2 2]*range(thickness)];
rectangle('Position',pos,'Curvature',[1 1],...
    'FaceColor',[1 1 1],'LineWidth',3)
axis equal
set(gca,'Color','none');

% thickness line, tick lables and axis label
line(Xax,[0 0],'LineWidth',1,'Color','r')
text(thickness-3,zeros(1,numel(thickness)),num2str(thickness.'),...
    'FontSize',16,'Color','r','VerticalAlignment','Bottom',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','right')
text(mean(thickness),0,'Thickness','FontSize',14,...
    'Color','r','VerticalAlignment','Top',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','center')
set(get(gca,'XAxis'),{'Limits','Visible'},{Xax,'off'});

% Azimuth line, tick lables and axis label
line([0 0],Yax,'LineWidth',3,'Color','k')
set(get(gca,'YAxis'),{'Limits','TickValues','TickLabels','FontSize'},...
    {Yax,Yax,[max(azimuth) min(azimuth)],14});
azimuth_thicks = azimuth(2:end-1); % get all the ticks yet to plot
azx = max(thickness)*sind(azimuth_thicks);
azy = max(thickness)*cosd(azimuth_thicks);
text(azx+2,azy,num2str(azimuth_thicks.'),'FontSize',14,...
    'VerticalAlignment','middle',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','Left')
text(max(thickness)*1.25,0,'Orientation','FontSize',16,'Rotation',90,...
    'VerticalAlignment','middle',...
    'HorizontalAlignment','Center')

% the data points:
x = data(:,2).*sind(data(:,1));
y = data(:,2).*cosd(data(:,1));
L = line(x,y,'Marker','x','LineStyle','none','Color','k',...
    'MarkerSize',10,'LineWidth',2);
```

[image: half circle]